# P-value correction for multiple comparisons using Mann–Whitney test (using R)

Tags: r, p-value, multiple-comparisons, wilcoxon-mann-whitney-test

I have questions regarding the adjusted p-value for multiple comparison using Mann–Whitney test.

The data structure that I am dealing with is something like this:

- Two groups to compare: Group 1 vs Group 2 (NOT pairwise)
- Each group having only 6 patients
- 200 proteins levels (continuous) were observed

[image: screenshot of tabular data with empty cells. Rows are patients and columns are proteins]

**Goal: 

I want to obtain a list of proteins that are significantly different between Group 1 and Group 2.**

If each group has a fairly large number of patients, then I would use t-test using an adjusted p-value. However, because we have only 6 patients, I would like to use the nonparametric test, Mann–Whitney test. 
I think I need to use the adjusted p-value in this case as well. However, I was not able to find how to correct p-value for the nonparametric case and an appropriate function in R.

**My question is:**
**1. Should I use the adjusted p-value?**
**2. If so, is there any formula or built-in function in R that can do it??**

Comment: Nonparametric tests tend to be fairly inefficient - typically, we use the t-test when we need to make some assumptions to achieve sufficient power. Furthermore, rank-based tests like MWU really struggle when you have both a small sample AND a multiple comparisons correction. What's your reasoning for using MWU instead of the t-test?

Comment: @rishi-k t.test assumes normality, so if the data is not normal MWU may be more indicated for the comparison. In my opinion, you should use the Bonferroni correction.

Comment: The t test is quite robust to non-normality - more importantly, it tends to become conservative in the face of non-normality. However, MWU is much more conservative due to conditioning only on the data - at n = 6 per group, the minimum p-value is 0.005, with which 200 hypotheses and using Bonferroni (or Bonferroni-Holm), has literally 0 power to detect any difference at all.